# Getting errorlevel from usebackq

Tags: batch-file

i've ran into a problem with adding registry keys using reg.exe via batch.
I'm using this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\iNiT" /v Basic`) DO (
SET BASICVALUE=%%A %%B

)
ECHO ERROR: %ERRORLEVEL%
```

EDIT:
Normaly REG.exe outputs a errorlevel when executed;
0 - Successful
1 - Failed

And i get:

```
ERROR:
```

Somehow the errorlevel gets wiped or not saved.
I need to get the %errorlevel% out of it when executed, how do i do this, this dosn't seem to work.
Can you somehow set the errorlevel to a variable? I've tested this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\iNiT" /v Basic && SET ERROR=%ERRORLEVEL%`) DO (
SET BASICVALUE=%%A %%B

)
ECHO %ERROR%
```

Nor does that work.

```
%% wasn't expected
```

Any information would be helpful :)

Comment: You would need to supply a less-heavily pruned code sample. Your first result means that there is a user-defined variable called `errorlevel` set to (probably) a space or space-string. To set `%errorlevel%` into a variable within a block (parenthesised series of statements) you'd need to be in `delayedexpansion mode` - can't see enough of your code to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Maggo I think the problem is solved but thanks anyways.

Comment: I have the same Problem. I think the reason is, you yust get the errorlevel of the FOR command and not the errorlevel of the command in the backticks. Unfortunally I dont have a solution for this yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\iNiT" /v Basic > tempFile.txt
echo %errorlevel%
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (tempFile.txt) DO (
   SET BASICVALUE=%%A %%B
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the below code in one of my script and may answer your question -

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\VisualSVN\VisualSVN Server" /V RepositoriesRoot >nul 2>&1 & if %errorlevel%==1 (echo.Visual SVN not installed)
```

Cheers, G

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, but the problem is solved now. I'll also be sure to test your code later on @gbabu